# Responsive results on filtered results page

Tags: javascript, html, css

We are looking to produce filtered answers based on users selecting tagged content and we've built a demo of the site [here](https://www.cilip.org.uk/page/Testinglearningresources) using this [online tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_portfolio_gallery_filter) as a starting point.

We're generally happy with the outcome apart from how it renders in mobile where the results are shown three across rather than stacked one on top of the other.

[Filtered results on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRXkT.jpg)

```
    <head>
<meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Center website */
.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 8px -16px;
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column (if you want) */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none; /* Hide columns by default */
}

/* Clear floats after rows */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Content */
.content {
  background-color: #ededee;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f2f2f3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #b8b8b9;
}

/* Add a dark background color to the active button */
.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
   color: white;
}
</style>
<script>
filterSelection("all") // Execute the function and show all columns
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}

</script>

<div class="cpContainer">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h2><font color="#164a5d">Learning resources</font></h2>
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button><br><br>
<b>Filter by PKSB Category</b><br>
  <button class="btn" "style=background-color:red" onclick="filterSelection('organising')"> <b>1. Organising Knowledge & Information</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('knowledge')"> <b>2. Knowledge & Information Management</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('exploiting')"> <b>3. Using & Exploiting Knowledge & Information</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('skills')"> <b>4. Research Skills</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('information')"> <b>5. Information Governance & Compliance</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('records')"> <b>6. Records Management & Archiving</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('collection')"> <b>7. Collection Management & Development</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('learning')"> <b>8. Literacies & Learning</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('leadership')"> <b>Leadership & Advocacy</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('strategy')"> <b>Strategy Planning & Management</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('customer')"> <b>Customer Focus, Service Design & Marketing</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('communication')"> <b>IT & Communication</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('ethics')"> <b>Ethics & Values</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('widerlib')"> <b>Wider Library, Information & Knowledge Sector</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('widerorg')"> <b>Wider Organisation & Environment</b></button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('career')"> <b>Career Development</b></button>
<br>
<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
```

Any help that could be provided would be gratefully received

Comment: You have not really asked a question nor stated any problems as such so this is a little hard to answer.

Comment: Problem is the results aren't displaying properly on a mobile phone - see attached screenshot "Filtered results on mobile". What I would like to happen is when the results are viewed on a mobile, the results stack one on top of the other rather than show three abreast. I hope that clarifies